# Script for multiple "sticky/follow" scrollbars using a common class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

Following a tutorial from [Andrew Henderson's blog](http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-sidebar/), I have the following jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stickyTop = $('.sticky').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (top < windowTop) {
            $('.sticky').css({ position: 'fixed', top: '10px' });
        }
        else {
            $('.sticky').css('position','static');
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine when my page has one **sticky sidebar**. However, when my page has multiple **sticky sidebars**, all of them scroll when the first **sidebar** starts to stick.

Is there a way that I can modify the script to only make the **sidebars** that are in the range start to stick?

Comment: Can't you wrap the scrolling content into a single div with the sticky class?

Comment: @Scott I have several divs that are on different sides of the page, and at different heights. I need each of them to catch only when they get down far enough, and I'd prefer to use the .sticky class rather than an id for each one of them.